# Typescript - Function with multiple parameters as callback

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code :

```js
function builder<T extends Foo>(
  getItems: (...) => Promise<T[]>, /* unsure what to put between parenthesis here */
) {
  return async (...): Promise<Baz> => { 
    const items = await getItems(...); /* unsure what to put between parenthesis here */
    // some manipulation here
    return items;
}
```

My goal is to allow the `builder` function to accept an asynchronous callback. This callback can be called with various types of parameters. There could be one, or many parameters inside the callback.

For example, I could call the `builder` function such as :

```js
// call 1 
builder<SomeResult>((a, b) => someCallback(a, b));

// call 2
builder<AnotherResult>((c) => otherCallback(c));
```

I'm pretty new to typescript so not quite sure how to do this. I think maybe i should look into [rest arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-arguments) but not exactly sure how to tackle the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot for the tips.

Comment: When the function you pass can take multiple arguments, where do those arguments come from? You can't just produce them out of nowhere.

Comment: Agreed, but my point was, those arguments (a, b, c) could be of any type. For example a could be a date, b could be a number, c could be a boolean. In the `builder` i just want to be able to call `getItems` with whatever arguments were passed via the callback.

Comment: ...but the arguments passed to the callback are the arguments that you call `getItems` with, so how would `builder` know what to pass?

Comment: `getItems` is the callback function. I want `builder` to pass whatever arguments I have specified when defining my callback (a, b, or c). With your answer, you've got me doubting that this is even possible, but I would have thought so. XD

Comment: I've updated my code to show that these parameters will also be passed via `return async (...): Promise<Baz> => { `.

Comment: Do you mean variable number of parameters when you say "multiple"? Because `function (a:any, b:any, c:any, d:any)` takes multiple arguments and there is nothing special about it

Comment: Yes, I mean multiple. For instance, you could call getItems with a set of parameters. This set could vary in length and in the types of the parameters provided.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody googles this, finally went with :

```js
function builder<T extends Foo>(
  getItems: (...addedParams: any[]) => Promise<T[]>, 
) {
  return async (...addedParams: any[]): Promise<Baz> => { 
    const items = await getItems(...addedParams); 
    // some manipulation here
    return items;
}
```